# Notify when network connection changes like network connected or disconnected

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to show popup window when a connection is lost or back for that I am us below code

```
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using Tulpep.NotificationWindow;

public TaskList()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged += AvailabilityChanged;
        load();
    }

    private void AvailabilityChanged(object sender, NetworkAvailabilityEventArgs e)
    {
        PopupNotifier popup = new PopupNotifier();
        if (e.IsAvailable)
        {
            popup.ContentText = "Network connected!";
            popup.Popup();
        }
        else
        {
            popup.ContentText = "Network disconnected!";
            popup.Popup();
        }
    }
```

But it cannot show a notification. I also apply to debug but it is not hit the debugger what is wrong here I don't know please help me in my code

Comment: That event is raised when no network adapters (except for tunnel and some - not all - looback adapters) are connected to a network. If a connection is available, the event is not raised. If you have WireShark installed, the NpCap loopback adapter is considered a valid connection, for example. If you disconnect everything except this one, the event will not be raised.

Comment: Would it be enough to check every n seconds? You can in fact check the operational status of each network interface, but you have to poll :(

Comment: can you give an example or link

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the [Ping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.devices.network.ping?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_VisualBasic_Devices_Network_Ping_System_Uri_System_Int32_) method periodically.  That call will return a result, and when it fails that might indicate you've disconnected.  However, this does rely on you having a reliable IP (or url) to use.

The basic test goes like this:

```
var reliableIP = "127.0.0.1";
var stillConnected = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping().Send(reliableIP, 500).Status == System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPStatus.Success;
```

How you use that will depend upon the kind of monitoring you want.

Comment: Can you give an example, please